# m2m table not changing column name after model name change

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I just switched out the django `User` model for a `CustomUser` model. I've got a field called `contributor_id` in a `Project` model which is a m2m field connected to the `User` model. I've told the m2m field to point to the `CustomUser` model and have run `makemigrations` and `migrate` but the `user_id` field has not changed to `customuser_id`. This is causing the following error:

> Unknown column 'projects_project_contributor_id.customuser_id' in 'field list'

I found these bug reports: [bug1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23630) and [bug2](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29000) but they both appear to have been fixed in 2.0. Obviously I can just run an alter table query on my database, but I don't know if:

a) There's away to get the django orm to do the change, and

b) if altering the tables directly will get my migrations out of wack.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) which explains that changing AUTH_USER_MODEL mid-flight is not super easy. There's a link to the steps to take ([here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313))

Comment: The issue #25313 got an update 3 days ago :-) with a pretty thorough step-by-step guide to do the migration.

Comment: Thanks the issue update was helpful.